# Algebraic extension $K/F$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F \subseteq K$ fields and R such that $F \subseteq R \subseteq K$. I showed that given the algebraic extension $K/F$, $R$ is a field, but what happen when the extension $K/F$ is not algebraic? I'm a little confused.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K/F$ is an algebraic extension if and only if every intermediate ring is a field. If it is not algebraic then there is some $\alpha\in K$ transcendental over $F$. Then $F[\alpha]$ is a ring which is not a field.